# Como enviar los datos obtenido del Content Provider de android a una base de datos Mysql utilizando php

Tags: php, java, mysql, android

Me interesaria saber como puedo enviar los datos obtenido del Content Provider a una base de datos mysql con php.
Con este codigo obtengo la duracion y el numero de la ultima llamada realizada:

```
 Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

    managedCursor.moveToLast();
    String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
    String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
    String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
    Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
    String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
    String dir = null;
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);

    if(dir.equals("OUTGOING")){
        //whatever you want here
        return "yes";
    }

    managedCursor.close();
    return "no";
```

Entonce me interesaria saber como enviar esos datos a mi base de datos mysql, he intentado de todo pero no he podido dar con la solucion

Este es mi codigo con el cual estoy enviando la peticion:

```
private void savedatabase(String call_number, String call_duration) {

    // url to post our data
    String url = "https://10.0.0.4/gci_webService/save_call_ejemplo.php";

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("TAG", "RESPONSE IS " + response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to get response = " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("call_log_number", call_number);
            params.put("call_duration", call_duration);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Este el codigo php con el cual resivo la peticion:

```
 <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "crud_prueba";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$response = array();
if($_POST['call_log_number'] && $_POST['call_log_duration']){

    $call_log_number = $_POST['call_number'];
    $call_log_duration = $_POST['call_duration'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `cursodb`(`call_log_number`, `call_log_duration`) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$call_log_number,$call_duration);
if($stmt->execute() == TRUE){
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "course created successfully!";
    } else{
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "failed\n ".$conn->error;
    }
} else{
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Insufficient parameters";
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Pero no meenvia los datos, no se esta enviando la solicitud al servidor y no se cual es el problema

Comment: Llamemos a lo que quieres hacer una *Tarea*. En Android las hay de tres tipos: Inmediatas, Diferidas y Exactas. Lo primero es decidir qué tipo de tarea requieres aquí y en base a eso usar la herramienta adecuada. Sugiero que revises [este artículo introductorio](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) en la documentación de Android. Y cuando tengas claro el tipo de tarea requerido ensayes un código y si tienes problemas concretos de ayudaremos.

Comment: Perdon pero soy nuevo en el mundo del desarrollo android, y todo lo que he logrado es ha base de tutoriales y lectura, soy desarrollador web, con el codigo posteado me permite acceder al content provider y obtener la ultima llamada telefonica realizada y su duracion, y quiero enviar esa informacion obtenida a mi base de datos con fines de reporte a mi sistema

Comment: Entiendo. Pero no queda claro en qué momento debe ocurrir eso, ni con qué frecuencia, por eso te decía en mi anterior comentario que lo primero es tener claro qué tipo de *Tarea* quieres realizar y en base a eso decidirte por alguna de las herramientas disponibles para ello. Dado que la base de datos está en un sitio remoto, necesitarás sin duda Retrofit, Volley u otra librería para la comunicación de red.

Comment: Exacto, la idea es que cada vez que se realice una llamada desde mi aplicacion, esta envie ese informe a la base de datos, que envie el ultimo numero marcado mas la duracion de la misma, el codigo posteado ya me permite obtener esos datos pero me falta enviarlo ahora a la base de datos, ya he probado con volley, pero no se como implementarlo

Comment: Puede que necesites un [Adaptador de Sincronización](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter), o bien programar un Workmanager que te sincronice los datos cada X tiempo. No sé, en este caso ni siquiera veo claro cuál sería la mejor herramienta.

Comment: Pues no realmente cada x tiempo, quiero que envie el datos cada vez presione determinado boton para realizar la llamada y esa finalice, al finalizar la llamada pueda enviar esos datos a mi servidor @A.Cedano

Comment: Pues si ya recoges los datos como dices, sólo tienes que programar una petición Volley que mande esos datos al servidor remoto. Pero OJO, en el servidor remoto tendrás que programar código (PHP por lo general) que recoja esos datos y los guarde en la base de datos.

Comment: Siii ya he realizo el codigo php, lo que no se es implementar eso en codigo java, no se como implemetar para que recoja esos valores y lo envie @A.Cedano

Comment: Pues eso se hace con Volley (o Retrofit u otra librería). Recogerías los datos en un HashMap por ejemplo y los mandarías al servidor. Aquí mismo hay varias respuestas sobre Volley y en la red hay tutoriales. Debes investigar y escribir tu código y si tienes algún problema concreto te ayudaremos a resolverlo. Comprende que aquí se requiere un punto de partida desde el cual podremos ayudarte. Ese punto de partida implica elegir una herramienta y escribir un código en base a esa herramienta. No podemos hacer eso por ti.

Comment: @A.Cedano Por eso he publicado el codigo pero estoy atascado en esa parte, no puedo seguir avanzando hasta que pueda lograr eso, mecione que probe con volley pero no lo pude lograr, he investigado bastante pero en la red no aparece para enviar datos desde el content provider hacia una base de datos, incluso en mi login utilizo volley para enviar la peticion atraves del la url, Pero todavia no logro implementar para que me envie los datos obtenido desde el content provider de android

Comment: Como ya dije, puedes tomar los datos del Content Provider, meterlos en un HashMap y usar ese HashMap para crear tu petición Volley. Si ya has programado código basado en Volley no será muy complicado y si no puedes publicas el código y nos dices los errores que tienes. No sirve decir: *he intentado esto* sin que veamos ese intento y los posibles errores que tengas en ese punto.

Comment: Vuelvo y te digo que lo que se es a base de tutoriales y lectura, libros pdf, no sabría como implementarlo, pero descuide gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: Ok, pero en base a lo que has investigado/entendido agrega a la pregunta el código con el que estás intentando pasar los datos al servidor y te ayudaremos a resolver el problema. En el código actual no hay tal intento. [Aquí hay un ejemplo de petición POST con Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46212722/5587982) donde se pasan datos al servidor. Las últimas versiones de Volley te permiten crear un JSON y pasarlo en el cuerpo de la petición directamente. Intenta algo así y dinos si tienes problemas o errores concretos para ayudarte a resolverlos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ahi he agregado los codigo utilizado, pero no me esta guardando los datos en la base de datos !

Comment: Lo que yo veo son incongruencias en tu archivo .php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A modo de posible respuesta (la estoy haciendo desde mi teléfono, puede que haya errores). Primero, establecemos los permisos de **internet** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Segundo, ¿Estás seguro que tu **url** es `https` y no `http`? Recuerda que si es http debes añadir la siguiente línea en tu `Manifest`:

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Tercero, antes de enviar los datos al servidor, controla con un `Log.d` o un `Toast` o lo que gustes, que los datos estan siendo captados y que no lleguen nulos.

Cuarto, si lo anterior está ok, vamos a tu archivo `php`. Lo que me llama la atención, sin prestar demasiada atención es que a tu método en `Volley` les pasas este valor:

```
call_log_number
call_log_duration
```

Pero en tus variables de tu archivo php al `insert` jamás se los asignas. Por lo que no habrá nunca un insert con los parámetros que envías:

`$call_log_number = $_POST['call_number'];`

Tu archivo debería quedar más o menos así:

```
<?php
  //Establezco los datos de conexión del servidor
  try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crud_prueba", "root", "");
    //Muestro un error en caso de que no se conecte
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: No se podido establecer la conexión. " . $e->getMessage());
  }

  // Establezco la función de insert con los datos a recibir
  try{
    $call_log_number= $_POST['call_number'];
    $call_log_duration = $_POST['call_duration'];

    // Creo el insert con parámetros
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cursodb (call_log_number, call_log_duration ) VALUES (:number,  :duration)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    // Asocio los parámetros a los campos del html
    $stmt->bindParam(':number', $call_log_number);
    $stmt->bindParam(':duration', $call_log_duration);

    //Ejecuto lo establecido
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Insertado.";
  } catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: No se ha podido insertar el registro: $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
  }

  //Cierro la conexión
  unset($pdo);
?>
```

Puedes modificar el archivo php a tu medida, yo lo hice siguiendo el diseño de lo que tú nos muestras.
por último, tu método debe quedar así:

```
private void savedatabase(final String number, final String duration) {

    // url to post our data
    String url = "https://10.0.0.4/gci_webService/save_call_ejemplo.php";

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("TAG", "RESPONSE IS " + response);
            try {
                if(response.contains("Insertado."){ 
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Insertado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {//toast no insertado}
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to get response = " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("call_number", number);
            params.put("call_duration", duration);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Y ya con eso debería estar solucionado tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me realiza la peticion deseada y me permite guardar los datos !

Comment: Que bueno saber que ya te funciona correctamente :)